# Is it ok to post HTML code I made from free PSD templates I found on the internet?

Tags: discussion

I want to practice my HTML and I was thinking about coding some free templates I found on the internet. Can I post the template and the HTML I wrote so you can review it?

Comment: Please check the license of the template to verify that it allows remixing and sharing.

Comment: If the license says it's ok to do such things then it would be ok to post the HTML in here for reviews?

Comment: How does this question differ from the previous one you asked http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/6919/can-i-remake-other-peoples-websites-using-html-css-only-for-education-purposes/6921#6921

Comment: as long as the license is ok and the question fits the site rules, you should be ask about it.

Comment: The difference is now I just want to post the HTML and I thought it would be too basic to be posted or something and now I'm talking about coding free psd templates.